# Kotlin - Automatically match overriden function type?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write a function that is essentially a wrapper method around some other functionality, for instance, some logging function.

I've tried several combinations of `inline`, `generic`, `reified`, etc., but nothing seems to work.

My function looks like this:

```
fun log(note: String, block: () -> Unit): () -> Unit {
    print(note)
    return block
}
```

My idea here is to perform some simple operation on the incoming `note`, and then just return that incoming function to be used as it was originally.

However, I want to do this around overridden functions like so:

```
override fun onClick(clicked: View) = log("Green Button") {
    // here the regular onClick functionality goes
}
```

Here, I get an error "**Return type is () -> Unit, which is not a subtype of overridden**". This makes sense enough, as the function signatures do not match.

However, when I do this with other random functions:

```
fun test() = log("foo") { ... }
fun otherTest(a: String, b: Int) = log("bar") { ... }
```

I get no errors, and the interpreter somehow seems fine with this. I also tried looking at something like `GlobalScope.launch` to take that approach, but I couldn't figure it out.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If not, is there something close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
inline fun log(note: String, block: () -> Unit): Unit {
    print(note)
    return block()
}
```

should do what you want. It can be generalized to

```
inline fun <T> log(note: String, block: () -> T): T {
    print(note)
    return block()
}
```

> I get no errors, and the interpreter somehow seems fine with this.

Why is that surprising? Those functions just return `() -> Unit`. If you do e.g.

```
fun test() = log("foo") { print("bar") }
```

then calling `test()` won't print `bar`; calling `test()()` will.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. Returning the function _invocation_ rather than just the function completely went over my head. I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if my understanding is wrong. This is my approach

Extension function:

```
fun View.onClickWithLog(str: String, l: () -> Unit) {
    setOnClickListener { Log.d("LogTag", str); run(l) }
}
```

Usage (from `Activity`):

```
btnTest.onClickWithLog("My Button String"){
            Log.d("Actions from Activity", "Content")
            finish()
        }
```

and the output is

```
 D/LogTag: My Button String
 D/Actions from Activity: Content
```

which prints your note first, and execute the actions in the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `=` operator to assign something to a `fun`, the expression on the right hand side is supposed to return the return type of that `fun`

The original `fun onClick(clicked:View) : Unit` has return type `Unit`. When you write

`override fun onClick(clicked:View) = ...` , the `...` is what you get when you call `onClick(v)` so it should be a `Unit` instead of a `View -> Unit` (Not even `() -> Unit` as in your code)

Take a simpler example. Let say you have `fun sum(a:Int,b:Int) : Int`. When you write `override fun sum(a:Int,b:Int) = ...` , `...` must be an `Int` instead of a `(Int,Int) -> Int` since you expect to get an `Int` immediately when you call `sum(a,b)`. If you somehow got a let say

`val someOtherWayToSum : (Int,Int) -> Int = {...}`

and want to use it, you can write

`override fun sum(a:Int,b:Int) = someOtherWayToSum(a,b)`

In your case, you better just do

```
override fun onClick(clicked:View){
    /* some operation (e.g your log)*/
    /* the regular onClick functionality */
}
```

since you are overriding it and implementing its regular functionality right there anyway.